# Replace CMYK images with RGB using AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, imagemagick-convert

I have to run a process to convert CMYK images to RGB using imagemagick. Something like this php exec command.

```
exec("/usr/bin/convert -verbose -density 300 -profile /var/www/html/pdf-cmyk/ISOnewspaper26v4.icc -profile /var/www/html/pdf-cmyk/AdobeRGB1998.icc '".$destination_path.$filename. "'  '" .$destination_path.$filename .".jpg'");
```

How do I do that in AWS lambda?

Comment: What kind of runtime are you planning to use? Node.js?

Comment: Anything that I can use. I have no plans to restrict myself on the runtime type.

Comment: `imagemagick` is available in the Lambda environment, you can interact with it with [`gm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm), see also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: question. How do I incorporate the .icc into the profile?

Comment: You will have to integrate your `.icc` files in your Lambda package.